# How to write serialized matrix to binary file in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the following 3x2 Int16 matrix as "test_matrix":

```
10  4
10  8
4   10
```

And I am expecting a binary output of 12 bytes

```
0x0A 0x04 0x0A 0x08 0x04 0x0A
```

I tried the following option:

```
write("test.bin", htol(test_matrix))
```

And the output becomes

[image]

What I have found are:

1. The matrix gets serialized (which is what I want)
2. The matrix gets transposed (which I don't want...)
3. The integers become 64 bits instead of 16 bits
4. The first 15 bytes are useless bytes for me

Any idea how should I export serialized matrix into binary correctly..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

Ad 2) the matrix is not transposed - Julia uses column major order like e.g. Fortran. You can use `transpose` to transpose the matrix if you want row major order.

Ad 3) `htol` works only because you are on little endian machine; on big endian it would error - use `htol.(test_matrix)` instead to broadcast it. Also most probably you actually have 64-bit integers stored in your matrix.

With these comments it works as you expected on my machine:

```
julia> test_matrix = Int16[10 4; 10 8; 4 10]
3×2 Array{Int16,2}:
 10   4
 10   8
  4  10

julia> write("test.bin", htol.(transpose(test_matrix)))
12

julia> stat("test.bin")
StatStruct(mode=0o100666, size=12)

julia> read("test.bin")
12-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x0a
 0x00
 0x04
 0x00
 0x0a
 0x00
 0x08
 0x00
 0x04
 0x00
 0x0a
 0x00
```

(if you get a different result when running your code can you please specify what Julia version, what OS and what machine you are working on?)

Comment: I tried on my machine and still doesn't work... I have Julia version 1.5.0, Windows OS (x86_64-w64-mingw32)m LIBM: libopenlibm, LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, sandybridge)

Comment: This is very strange. I have all the same but instead of sandybridge I have skylake but it should not matter. Can you post on https://discourse.julialang.org/ what output you get when you run my code and mention me, because it seems it might require more discussion.

Comment: It worked, the mistake is on my end. Thanks very much for your help!